# Why does incrementing this Deque's iterator write garbage to a struct that has been copied from it?

Tags: c++

I am having an interesting problem. This C++ code is meant to simulate a job scheduler with different approaches to how they are scheduled. In my code meant to simulate SFS (shortest job first) scheduling, the struct contained in current_task has garbage written to each of its members, particularly processId and cpuBursts, which each assume a value that is around 134 million (for the first struct that is assigned to current_task, the processId is 100 and cpuBursts is 10. These values are populated correctly in the deque returned from the function that reads the input file). Each of the other members is zeroed out. I have attached some images containing my GDB debugging session in CLion.

My environment is the most recent version of CLion configured to use WSL with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and G++-9. My language level is set to C++17.

Note that the for loop around line 65 is commented out; I did this to see if merely getting and operating on an iterator was causing my problem. Line 72 also causes this same issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <optional>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

enum State {
    NEW,
    WAITING,
    READY,
    RUNNING,
    TERMINATED
};

typedef struct {
    int processId;
    int arrival_time;
    int cpuBursts;
    int priority;
    State state;

    string str() {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "[Task] ID: " << processId << ", Arrival Time: " << arrival_time << ", CPU Bursts: "<< cpuBursts << ", Priority: " << priority << ", State: " << state;
        return ss.str();
    }
} Task;

//Prototypes
deque<Task> read_input();
int main();
void FCFS(deque<Task>);
void SJF(deque<Task>);

//Functions
int main() {
    auto v = read_input();
   // FCFS(deque<Task>(v));
    SJF(deque<Task>(v));

    return 0;
}


void SJF(deque<Task> tasks) {
//Note: This one doesn't bother considering arrival times since the order of execution and start times would be the same.
    bool running = true; // Keep iterating?
    int t = 0; // Time
    Task* current_task = nullptr; // The current task
    deque<Task> task_queue;

    for (auto &task : tasks) {
        // Set each task's state to ready. No point, really
        task.state = READY;
    }

    cout << "Beginning Shortest Job First (SJF) execution of " << tasks.size() << " tasks." << endl;

    while (running) {
        // Populate the task queue with any new tasks if necessary
        /*for (const auto &task : tasks) {
            if (task.arrival_time == t) {
                cout << "Task with ID " << task.processId << " arrived at t = " << t << endl;
                task_queue.push_back(task);
            }
        }*/

        auto it = tasks.begin()++;

        // Sort the task queue by shortest time
        sort(task_queue.begin(), task_queue.end(), [] (const Task& lhs, const Task& rhs) {
            return lhs.cpuBursts < rhs.cpuBursts;
        });


        // The current_task will only be nullptr if this is the very first iteration at t = 0
        // or a task had just finished executing on the previous iteration.
        if (current_task == nullptr) {
            // Since the tasks are sorted by CPU burst requirements, the front of the queue contains the shortest.
            Task new_current_task = task_queue.front();
            task_queue.pop_front();
            cout << "Task with ID " << new_current_task.processId << " has begun execution at t = " << t << endl;
            // Set the current task to RUNNING and update current_task.
            new_current_task.state = RUNNING;
            current_task = &new_current_task;
        }

        if (current_task->cpuBursts > 0) {
            current_task->cpuBursts -= 1;
            cout << "Task with ID " << current_task->processId << " has " << current_task->cpuBursts << " CPU bursts remaining." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Task with ID " << current_task->processId << " has completed execution at t = " << t << endl;
            current_task->state = TERMINATED;


            if (task_queue.empty()) {
                cout << "SJF execution is complete." << endl;
                running = false;
            }

            current_task = nullptr;
        }

        t++;
    }

}

void FCFS(deque<Task> tasks) {
    //Note: This one doesn't bother considering arrival times since the order of execution and start times would be the same.
    bool running = true; // Keep iterating?
    int t = 0; // Time
    Task* current_task = nullptr; // The current task
    auto vec_iterator = tasks.begin(); // Iterator used to navigate the deque containing the tasks

    for (auto &task : tasks) {
        // Set each task's state to ready. No point, really
        task.state = READY;
    }

    cout << "Beginning First Come First Serve (FCFS) execution of " << tasks.size() << " tasks.";

    while (running) {
        // The current_task will only be nullptr if this is the very first iteration at t = 0
        // or a task had just finished executing on the previous iteration.
        if (current_task == nullptr) {
            Task new_current_task = *(vec_iterator++); // Get the next task from the iterator; increment iterator by 1
            cout << "Task with ID " << new_current_task.processId << " has begun execution at t = " << t << endl;
            // Set the current task to RUNNING and update current_task.
            // State really isn't used for anything in FCFS so it doesn't really matter.
            new_current_task.state = RUNNING;
            current_task = &new_current_task;
        }

        if (current_task->cpuBursts > 0) {
            current_task->cpuBursts -= 1;
            cout << "Task with ID " << current_task->processId << " has " << current_task->cpuBursts << " CPU bursts remaining." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Task with ID " << current_task->processId << " has completed execution at t = " << t << endl;
            current_task->state = TERMINATED;

            if (vec_iterator == tasks.end() && current_task->state == TERMINATED) {
                cout << "FCFS Execution complete." << endl;
                running = false;
            }

            current_task = nullptr;
        }

        t++;
    }
}

deque<Task> read_input() {
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    string line;
    deque<Task> tasks;

    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Couldn\'t find or access input.txt." << endl;
        return tasks;
    }

    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        Task t;
        istringstream iss(line);

        if (!(iss >> t.processId >> t.arrival_time >> t.cpuBursts >> t.priority)) {
            cout << "Skipping line due to text..." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        t.state = NEW;
        tasks.push_back(t);
    }

    return tasks;
}
```

[image: Initial debug build and run]

The watcher of interest is current_task and its members. At this point, everything is fine.

[image: GDB window after stepping to the breakpoint where current_task is set correctly]

This is right towards the end of the first iteration. It maintains its correct state until right after the 2nd iteration starts.

[image: GDB window right after line 72 is executed]

Without fail, these garbage values are always around 134 million. I doubt this is significant though. This same behavior is exhibited when the for loop on lines 65-70 is uncommented and run and line 72 is commented out, so I have isolated this to the iterators, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Here you’re making a copy of the object:

```
Task new_current_task = *(vec_iterator++);

Task new_current_task = task_queue.front();
```

Then you put a pointer it into your `current_task`, and exit the scope. The object is destroyed. You have a dangling pointer to a destroyed object. Dereferencing it can do anything, in this case the memory is reused for something else and you see garbage.

The changes you make are also for a temporary object, not the one in the deque anyway. You need to use references, or some other way of keeping the object alive.

Note that you’re also calling the methods without references, so the deques also are copied, including the objects inside. Might not be what you want either.

Comment: Thank you so much! Copying the deques is intentional as some modifications are made to each struct in each function, and I want them to have the same initial state without reading the file more than once.